# Create a point for each line not-along the lines

Tags: qgis, point, lines-to-points

I would like to automatically create a vector of points.

The vector should be composed of one point per each line of a line vector (approx 3000 features). Those points should be placed near each line but not along them.
The best result would happen if points were created in a direction perpendicular to each line, 1 meter far from each line.

In order to have an example, the following image shows the desired result:
[image: Example: points with green signs are okay, the point with red cross is not okay.]

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 3.0/3.2 - **Geometry by expression** tool in 
`Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry`

Select your line layer as input, point as output geometry type, and apply:

```
centroid(offset_curve($geometry, 1))
```

Comment: Thx, I cannot find the tool using QGIS 2.18...Do I have to install 3.0/3.2?

Comment: @Giacomo Please see added QGIS 2.18 part.

Comment: Ok, copying the expression **centroid(offset_curve($geometry, 1))** gives me the "expression is invalid" error due to the offset_curve function..

Comment: @Giacomo I give up QGIS 2.18 case. Sorry. As QGIS 3.0/3.2 and QGIS 2.18 can run concurrently, your output from QGIS 3 can be brought back to QGIS 2.18 project.

Answer (score 1):

The method provided by Kazuhito is far more elegant, but in case you don't have access to QGIS 3.0/3.2, here are two methods for 2.18:

---

Create a 2 meter single-sided buffer with OGR > `Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines` tool (Processing Toolbox)

Use `Polygon Centroids` tool (Processing Toolbox) to create centroids of buffers.

---

Create a point on line layer using one of these tools from the Processing Toolbox:

- QGIS > `Random points along line`
- OGR > `Create points along lines`
- GRASS > `V.to.points`

Select all features in point layer, use `Move Feature(s)` tool (editing toolbar) to move them.

---

Check the results of either method by using `Spatial Query` to select features of the points layer that intersect features in the lines layer.

Use the `Move Feature(s)` tool to move them away from the lines they intersect.

Comment: Great, thanks @csk This issue has been bothering my head all day today.